# PyMongo Get All Values of an Index for Sharded Cluster

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, sharding

I have a sharded cluster and the index information:

```
client.test_db.test_collection.index_information()
```

is as follows:

```
{'_id_': {'key': [('_id', 1)], 
          'ns': 'test_db.test_collection', 
          'v': 2}, 
 'test_id_hashed': {'key': [('test_id', 'hashed')], 
                    'ns': 'test_db.test_collection',
                    'v': 2}}
```

I need to loop over all of the documents within the collection:

```
for doc in client.test_db.test_collection.find({}):
    do_something(doc)
```

However, it seems slow as the query needs to look look through all shards in order to find each document. I believe that it would be faster if I could loop over each document by the id since it is indexed but I can't seem to find a fast way to retrieve all of the id values aside from:

```
ids = []
for doc in client.test_db.test_collection.find({}):
    ids.append(doc['test_id'])
```

Is there a better (faster) way to obtain this list of values for the indexed id? Since I have a sharded cluster, calling the `find()` function without providing a shard key appears to be costly.

Comment: *"I need to loop over all of the documents within the collection..."* - Why? Presumably you want to "do something" with the data and if you return ALL the data with no filtering then ( particularly since sharded are usually huge ) then that is a lot of work and will take a lot of time. Seems like your question is missing the vital "do something" part, which can possibly be done a lot better if you cared to share this vital thing.

Comment: I'm building machine learning models and each document serves as a data point (or set of features). Hence, I need all documents. So, the `do_something` will be to generate features for each document. Of course, in the future, I might subset some documents, say, by date but I only have about 15K documents and it is slow to retrieve so I want to make sure I'm not missing anything.